# How to run meson build system on windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, meson-build

I would like to use meson build system on windows.
I am python noob.
It looks like I installed it, but I do not know how to run it.

I have installed python 3.6.
I have installed meson from 'cmd':

```
C:\>python -m pip install meson
Collecting meson
  Downloading meson-0.39.0.tar.gz (558kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 563kB 866kB/s
Installing collected packages: meson
  Running setup.py install for meson ... done
Successfully installed meson-0.39.0
```

I try to run meson:

```
C:\>python -m meson
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe: No module named meson


C:\>meson
'meson' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I use/run this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the documentation

> Running
>
> Meson requires that you have a source directory and a build directory
>   and that these two are different. In your source root must exist a
>   file called 'meson.build'. To generate the build system run this
>   command:
>
> meson
>
> Depending on how you obtained Meson the command might also be called
>   meson.py

check for a meson.py in the directory that you installed meson.

https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson

Comment: Yes. `meson.py` solves it. Thats what is missing on the meson home page.

Comment: awesome, since this answered your  question please mark this as the answer so we can help other find it.

Comment: Just running `meson.py` does not work unless you a) have it in your path, and b) have set all `.py` files to open with `python.exe` (no thanks). And even then it doesn't seem to pass arguments.

Answer (score 9):

Ok the [official advice](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#launcher) is to associate `.py` files with the Windows Python Launcher (at `c:\Windows\py.exe`). However this is a shitty solution because a) That means you can't associate them with an editor or IDE, and b) command line argument passing e.g. `meson.py --help` does not work.

A better solution is to:

1. Download and install Python 3 to the default installation location (in `%APPDATA%`). Have it add Python to your path.
2. Run `python -m pip install meson`
3. Create a `meson.bat` file somewhere in your `PATH` with the following contents:

   ```
   @echo off
   c:\Windows\py.exe %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\meson.py %*
   ```

Then you should be able to just run `meson --help` successfully.

I have no idea why this isn't done automatically.

Comment: Your point b) is not true (anymore?). meson --help, setup --help-commands, etc. work, at least in Windows 10 with Python 3.6.6.

Comment: Did you run `meson.py --help` or `meson --help`? [Here is the issue for this problem by the way](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/1877).

Comment: Both `meson --help` and `meson.py --help` work. Also, setup.py from pycairo and pygobject builds work both ways.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

1. Download the latest MSI for Windows form the [Releases](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/releases) page.
2. Use [LessMSI](https://github.com/activescott/lessmsi) to extract the MSI into my own folder.
3. Create a `bat` file which opens a `CMD` with the path to `Meson` added to the System Variable `%PATH%`.

Then just use it as guided form the `CMD`.
No need to install Python or anything.

Comment: Indeed, I see the MSI file just includes a directly runnable meson.exe, no need for separate Python installation, as it comes with a standalone Python DLL. I just installed the MSI (double click) though to the path I wanted, rather than use 7-zip or LessMSI.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 / Python 3.9

```
pip3 install meson
```

meson.exe will be installed in Scripts folder

```
c:\users\<usernmae>\appdata\roaming\python\pythonxx\Scripts\meson.exe
```